# Can I use border-radius in selection like in vscode?

Tags: css

Somethings like this...

[VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlT02.png)

```css
::selection{
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I try somethings like it, but failed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is 'No'.

Slightly longer explanation, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection)

> Only certain CSS properties can be used with ::selection:
>
> color background-color text-decoration and its associated properties
> text-shadow stroke-color, fill-color and stroke-width In particular,
> background-image is ignored.

Unfortunately this means that we can't even create something like a set of gradient images to make it look as though there is a border.

Comment: emm... Well, but how can I make this effect?